# Reset value in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive: `timelineItem` that's being repeated through a `ng-repeat`. So there can be 1-100 (or more) instances of the directive in the application.

All these timeline-item elements have nested templates in them and I want to wait until the `ng-includes` are finished loading and then do something. So I put a `onload="vm.templateFinishedLoading()"` on the includes.

This is the function that's being called:

```
public templatesFinishedLoading() {
    this.i += 1;
    if (this.i === this.activities.items.length) {
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('templatesFinishedLoading');
    }
}
```

Since there can be multiple templates being loaded I don't want to call the `$broadcast` multiple times I've put in a for loop. So when all the templates are done loading it does the broadcast.

I want to call a function when the template is done loading so this `$broadCast` is caught in the `timelineItem` directive. Since each instance of the directive catches the `$broadcast` and I only want to animate of a clicked element I have to compare the clicked HTMLelement in the DOM with the HTMLelement of the directive:

```
element.on('click', () => {
    clickedElement = attr.$$element[0].parentElement;
}
```

Then on the `$broadcast` I compare the clickedElement with the attribute element:

```
scope.$on('templatesFinishedLoading', () => {
    if (attr.$$element[0].parentElement === clickedElement) {
        console.log('true');
    }
});
```

This always equals to true since I only update the `clickedElement` variable on the clicked directive. The `clickedElement` variable in the other instances are not updated since they are outside the scope of the current directive.

So I added another `$broadcast` to the click:

```
element.on('click', () => {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('resetClickedElement');
    clickedElement = attr.$$element[0].parentElement;
}
```

And then in the same directive I catch the broadcast:

```
scope.$on('resetClickedElement', () => {
    clickedElement = document.createElement('div');
});
```

So now when I click on the element that has the directive:

```
<div class="activity-header" timeline-item>
```

I first broadcast the reset to all other instances of the directive to change the `clickedElement` to a empty div element. Then I set the current clicked element to the clickedElement variable. So now when the template is finished loading all the instances of the directive do the `if (attr.$$element[0].parentElement === clickedElement)` and only the clicked directive will  have the correct `clickedElement` since all the other are empty.

So now my question. Is there a other method of "resetting" the `clickedElement` variable in each directive instance?

Comment: I would suggest you to have a service to store the clicked element and also a boolean to check if the templates finished their loading. In the directive controller you could watch both variables and have a set method to update the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is that you implement something like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-repeat="item in [].constructor(10) track by $index">
    <div timeline-item></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your application:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('timelineController', TimelineController)
.directive('timelineItem', TimelineItem)
.factory('timelineService', TimelineService);

function TimelineController ($scope, $element, timelineService) {
    timelineService.updateLoadedItems();

    if (timelineService.isLoadFinished()) {
        console.log('finished load the directives');
    }

}

TimelineController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', 'timelineService'];

function TimelineItem (timelineService) {
    return {
        template: '<div> timeline item {{selectedItem}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    timelineService.setClickedElement(element);
                });
            });

            scope.$watch(function() {
              return timelineService.getClickedElement();
            }, function () {
                scope.selectedItem = timelineService.getClickedElement() === element;
            });
        },
        controller: TimelineController
      }
}

TimelineItem.$inject = ['timelineService'];

function TimelineService () {
  var loadedAllItems = false;
  var clickedElement = null;
  var itemsLength = 10;
  var loadedItems = 0;

  return {
    getClickedElement: function () {
        return clickedElement;
    },

    setClickedElement: function (element) {
        clickedElement = element;
    },

    resetClickedElement: function () {
        clickedElement = null;
    },

    isLoadFinished: function () {
        return loadedAllItems;
    },
    updateLoadedItems: function () {
      loadedItems++;
      loadedAllItems = loadedItems == itemsLength;
    }
  }
}
```

Doing this you don't need your broadcasts and will have the same effect.